# Call function in a Controller from Routes

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I have been searching for an answer to this, but haven't really found the real solution. I learned a bit of Laravel recently, and it had this type of routing:

```
Route::get('home', 'functionname@controllername');
```

As of now, I have left Laravel and am fiddling with CodeIgniter.

The routing I have here is:

```
$route['home'] = "controllername";
```

And the index function gets called. How can I mention the function I need to call, just like in Laravel?

Comment: I don't know laravel but I think this is what you want `$route['home'] = "controllername/functionname"`

Comment: I tried that, and it worked. Really bad structure I guess,when the controller is in a folder, it may get confusing `$route['home'] = "foldername/controllername/functionname"`

Comment: @ShaifulIslam - Can you please post it as an answer so that I can mark it as the right answer?

Comment: yes `foldername/controllername/functionname` is confusing.remember you can keep one layer folder under controller folder.More layer folder will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
$route['home'] = "controllername/functionname"
```

You can find lots of example at [codeigniter 2 docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Codeigniter-3 also supports callback function. You can see details [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can call any function of controller using routes, like this

```
$route['home'] = "YourController/Yourfunction"
```

when you hit http://example.com/home then it redirects you to "Yourfunction"

Answer (score 1):

If you want pass arguments for function

```
$route['home/(any:)'] = "yourcontroller/yourfunction"
$route['home/(any:)/num:'] = "yourController/yourfunction/$1/$2"
```

(any:) - for string, num: for numerical params and you could also use regexp

You can reorder params by $1 $2 etc,:

```
 $route['home/(any:)/num:'] = "yourcontroller/yourfunction/$2/$1"
```

link would look likie this:

```
home/blog/3
```

and function will be call : `yourfunction(3,'blog');`